# Isotope load images progessively

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope on a website I have built - it is used to position lots of JPEGs, along with a filtering system - this works well, but the load of the page is slow as I think Isotope has some issues loading lots of images...

The code I am using is as below:

```
$(window).load( function() {
  // init Isotope
  var $grid = $('.workGridWrapper').isotope({
    // options
  itemSelector: '.workGridItem',
  percentPosition: true,
  masonry: {
    // use element for option
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'

  },

  filter: '.InitialLoad'

  });

  // store filter for each group
  var filters = {};

  $('.filterGridInner').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // get group key
    var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
    var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
    // set filter for group
    filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
    // combine filters
    var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
    // set filter for Isotope
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.filterGridInner .button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'li', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.filterOn').removeClass('filterOn');
      $( this ).addClass('filterOn');
    });
  });

});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
  var value = '';
  for ( var prop in obj ) {
    value += obj[ prop ];
  }
  return value;
}
```

I am pretty sure the `window.load` function is the issue...

I have seen notes about using `imagesLoaded` - but not sure how to use it without messing up my current solution.

Any advice on making the page load much quicker? The total weight of the page is just 2.1MB with 1.7MB of that in images - but it seems to take 18 seconds to load when I test it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this codepen that uses both ImagesLoaded + isotope plugin. http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/bsHix

Comment: Thanks - I am really looking to adapt what I have already rather than use another solution

Answer (score 1):

First step you can take is to make sure all your images are optimized for the web (re-sized & compressed properly ).

Using **[ImagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)** is pretty much straight forward, you can call your isotope functions once the images within `.workGridItem`'s are loaded.

```
$(function(){
  $grid = $('.workGridWrapper');
  $grid.imagesLoaded( function() {
    // Init isotope here after images have loaded..
    $grid.isotope({..});
   });
});
```

Your HTML markup would look something like this :

```
<div class="workGridWrapper">
   <div class="workGridItem"><img src=".."/></div>
   <div class="workGridItem"><img src=".."/></div>
</div>
```

However, all this plugin does is detect if images are loaded and whether or not there are any broken links . It won't improve performance and change the fact you have large images on the page.

What I would do is create two versions of the images : Small size ( Thumbnails ) & Large Size ( High Resolution ) . Load Thumbnails first in your isotope then if the user clicks on it, fetch the High resolution version.

Instead of doing :

```
<div class="workGridItem"><img src="http://example.com/image.jpg"/></div>
```

Do

```
<div class="workGridItem">
  <a href="http://example.com/image.jpg">
    <img src="http://example.com/image_thumb.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Example**

```js
$(function() {

  var $grid = $('#workGridWrapper'),
    $photos = $grid.find('.workGridItem'),
    $loadingIndicator = $('<div class="loading"><span><img src="http://i.imgur.com/IE7iw.gif" /></span></div>');

  // Setup Isotope and call after Images are loaded
  $grid.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $grid.isotope({
      animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
      },
      itemSelector: '.workGridItem',
      masonry: {
        columnWidth: 200
      },
      percentPosition: true
    });
  });

  // toggle images version
  function enlargeImage($photo) {
    $photos.filter('.large').removeClass('large');
    $photo.addClass('large');
    $grid.isotope('reLayout');
  }

  // On click fetch large size image / toggle
  $photos.find('a').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $photo = $this.parents('.workGridItem');

    if ($photo.hasClass('large')) {
      $photo.removeClass('large');
      $grid.isotope('reLayout');
    } else {
      if ($photo.hasClass('has-big-image')) {
        enlargeImage($photo);
      } else {
        $this.append($loadingIndicator);
        var $bigImage = $('<img>', {
          src: this.href
        });

        $('<div>', {
            'class': 'big-image'
          })
          .append($bigImage)
          .appendTo($this)
          .imagesLoaded(function() {
            $loadingIndicator.remove()
            enlargeImage($photo);
          });
        $photo.addClass('has-big-image');

      }
    }

    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
#workGridWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
.workGridItem {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.workGridItem.double {
  width: 480px;
}
.workGridItem.large {
  width: 600px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.workGridItem.large .small-image,
.workGridItem .big-image {
  display: none;
}
.workGridItem .small-image,
.workGridItem.large .big-image {
  display: block;
}
.workGridItem img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.workGridItem .loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.7);
}
.workGridItem .loading span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
.workGridItem .loading img {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: -16px;
  top: -16px;
}
.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -moz-transition-property: height, width;
  transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
.isotope.no-transition,
.isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,
.isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/4.0.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.2/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div id="workGridWrapper" class="photos clearfix">
  <div class="workGridItem">
    <a href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4113/5013039951_3a47ccd509_b.jpg">
      <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4113/5013039951_3a47ccd509.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="workGridItem">
    <a href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4131/5013039885_0d16ac87bc_b.jpg">
      <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4131/5013039885_0d16ac87bc.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="workGridItem">
    <a href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4086/5013039583_26717f6e89_b.jpg">
      <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4086/5013039583_26717f6e89.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="workGridItem">
    <a href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4144/5013039541_17f2579e33_b.jpg">
      <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4144/5013039541_17f2579e33.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="workGridItem">
    <a href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4146/5013646070_f1f44b1939_b.jpg">
      <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4146/5013646070_f1f44b1939.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="workGridItem">
    <a href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4153/5013039741_d860fb640b_b.jpg">
      <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4153/5013039741_d860fb640b.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="workGridItem">
    <a href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4113/5013039697_a15e41fcd8.jpg">
      <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4113/5013039697_a15e41fcd8_b.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="workGridItem">
    <a href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4124/5013646314_c7eaf84918.jpg">
      <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4124/5013646314_c7eaf84918.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="workGridItem">
    <a href="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4089/5013040075_bac12ff74e.jpg">
      <img class="small-image" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4089/5013040075_bac12ff74e_b.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

If your isotope is an image gallery and not only links, you may want to have a look at [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) which has a nice API.

```
<div class="workGridItem">
  <a href="http://example.com/image1.jpg" rel="group">
    <img src="http://example.com/image_thumb1.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://example.com/image2.jpg" rel="group">
    <img src="http://example.com/image_thumb2.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>


$(function(){ 
  var $grid = $('#workGridWrapper'),
      $photos = $grid.find('.workGridItem a');

  $grid.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $grid.isotope({
      animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
      },
      itemSelector: '.workGridItem',
      masonry: {
        columnWidth: 200
      },
      percentPosition: true
    });

    //Call fancybox
    $photos.fancybox();
  }); 

});
```

I hope you find it useful

Comment: Thanks for your lengthy response Raja - I found another factor which was contributing to the slow load of the page that had nothing to do with Isotope - so think, my solution in the respect of it's use of Isotope is actually already OK. Appreciate your efforts in proposing a new solution however.

Comment: No problem dubbs, Good luck!